# Ошибка CORS при запросе в vk.api

Tags: javascript, ajax, requests, cors, cross-domain

Перепробовал много вариантов, потратил пол дня сегодня. Не знаю, что делать

Ошибка:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.vk.com/method/users.search&access_token=TOKEN&v=5.101' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Код:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://api.vk.com/method/users.search&access_token=TOKEN&v=5.101', true);
// xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log('User\'s name is ' + xhr.responseText);
    } else {
        alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

В самом VK создал приложение. Порт менял на разные. Так же использовал тестовый домен, результат тот же.
[image: Приложение]

Comment: Используйте Javascript SDK вконтакте, методы те же - https://vk.com/dev/Javascript_SDK

Answer (score 2):

Сервер должен установить в заголовок ответа `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, а браузер пользователя, получив такой заголовок разрешает доступ к ресурсам этого домена, который не совпадает с текущим. Иными словами, можно сколько угодно писать на клиентской стороне  в хидере `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, но если сервер этого не позволяет, то попытки будут тщетны. Вывод прост: ответ сервера должен содержать в `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` либо адрес Вашего сайта, либо звездочку, и тогда всё заработает.

`Redirect_uri` — это URL, на который будет переадресован браузер пользователя после разрешения им прав доступа при получении ключа [Получение ключа доступа](https://vk.com/dev/access_token)

> При разработке веб-приложения с работой с API из Javascript, в
>   `redirect_uri` необходимо указать адрес страницы на Вашем сайте. В
>   целях безопасности, этот адрес также должен быть указан в настройках
>   Вашего приложения (поля «Адрес сайта», «Базовый домен» и «Доверенный
>   Redirect URI»).

Ссылка на документацию: [Что такое redirect_uri?](https://vk.com/faq11735)

Вам необходимо установить доверенный редирект URI в настройках Open API.